# Docker Issue : Cannot run the container (repository does not exist or may require 'docker login')

Tags: spring-boot, docker, minio

After I devise a Spring Boot project with the usage of MinIo, I tried to run it in Docker but I have an issue.

Here is my docker-compose.yaml file

```
version: '3.8'

services:
  minio:
    image: minio/minio:latest
    container_name: minio
    environment:
      MINIO_ACCESS_KEY: "minioadmin"
      MINIO_SECRET_KEY: "minioadmin"
    volumes:
      - ./data:/data
    ports:
      - 9000:9000
      - 9001:9001
```

I firstly run this command `docker-compose up -d`.
Then I run `docker ps -a` to check if it is located in container. After that, I run this command `docker run <container-id>` (a07fdf1ef8c4), here is a message shown below.

```
Unable to find image 'a07fdf1ef8c4:latest' locally
docker: Error response from daemon: pull access denied for a07fdf1ef8c4, repository does not exist or may require 'docker login': denied: requested access to the resource is denied.
See 'docker run --help'.
```

I also run this option shown below nothing changed.

```
C:\Users\host\IdeaProjects\SpringBootMinio>docker run -p 9000:9000 9001:9001 minio/minio:latest
Unable to find image '9001:9001' locally
docker: Error response from daemon: pull access denied for 9001, repository does not exist or may require 'docker login': denied: requested access to the resource is denied.
See 'docker run --help'.
```

Even if I run the command `docker login`, I couldn't fix it.

How can I solve it out?

Comment: What's the actual `docker run` command you're running?  What are you hoping to do with the second container?

Comment: @DavidMaze docker run a07fdf1ef8c4

Comment: Docker run takes an image name or id, not a container id.

Comment: @larsks Is it a right command (`docker run minio/minio:latest`)

Comment: Yes, that is a valid command because `minio/minio:latest` is a valid image name (it won't do much, other than display a help message from `minio` and exit, but it does run)

Comment: You don't need to `docker run` anything here: once you `docker-compose up -d`, the container is already running.  In the first example, as @larsks says, `docker run` takes an image name (or ID) and not a container ID, which is why you're getting that error; in the second, you're missing a `-p` in front of the second published port spec.

Comment: @DavidMaze You can say this `docker run -p 9000:9000 -p 9001:9001 minio/minio:latest`.  However,  I couldn't open localhost:9000 in browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1st Error**

`docker run <container-id>` - That is **not** how you run a container with Docker. When you run `docker-compose up -d`, it already starts the containers; in this case it's MinIO.

The `docker run` function requires an image name as the argument. So when you do `docker run <container-id>`, it tries to find an image with the container ID, which doesn't exist.

So when you do `docker-compose up -d`, it starts minio. You do not need to start it again.

**2nd Error**
When you run `docker run -p 9000:9000 9001:9001 minio/minio:latest`, you are basically saying that the image name is `9001:9001`. But no such image exists. If you want to expose another port, just do `docker run -p 9000:9000 -p 9001:9001 minio/minio:latest`. For every single port you want to expose, just do `-p` and enter the port mapping.